# Are pointers stored as integers?

Tags: pointers, language-agnostic

Are pointers in C/C++ (or any language for that matter), integers?  A pointer holds a memory address, from 0 to the upper limit of your memory. So in math terms, a pointer could be considered a non-negative integer.

How are pointers stored in C/C++? And in other popular languages?

Comment: That is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Depends what you mean.  A pointer is just a bunch of bits (in a register or another memory location); those bits can always be reinterpreted as an integer.

Comment: Pointers store a memory address.  The form of a memory address is hardware dependant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a couple of implicit questions here, so let's take each one that I understand is present.

First, are pointers in C/C++ just integeres with a disguise?

Yes, they are, and no, they're not. First, implementation-wise, the most common way to implement points is to just pick the right size of integer for the platform (32-bit or 64-bit) and use that as an absolute address value into addressable memory space.

In this context, you could say that pointers are just integers.

However, pointers in C/C++ has always been defined as black box data types. You're not *supposed* to use them as integers since they could very well not have what you would call a "numerical value" context that makes sense.

Certainly they *look* numerical, you can add integers to them to move past them and so on, but all of that is implementation specific, undocumented (on purpose), and thus not really reliable. What I mean by "reliable" here is that if you interpret the pointer as an integer, you should not rely on there being any meaningful relationship between the pointer and the integer.

For a *specific* platform, compiler, runtime, etc. you might find evidence that it doesn't have any special meaning beyond being treated as a numerical value that addresses a particular byte in addressable space, but I would still refrain from thinking of it that way. A pointer is a black box.

So the next question is if you can reinterpret the memory that holds a pointer as an integer. Well, yes, you can certainly do that, but again, you should consider the actual numerical value of that integer as meaningless. If you have a 32-bit pointer, you can store it in a 32-bit integer, and vice versa, but what that numerical value of the integer means, that I would not place any value on.

A particular implementation could very well take this:

```
p++;
```

to mean something like this:

```
i -= sizeof(element);
```

ie. reversed memory space. I don't know of any such environment, computer, runtime, compiler, or whatnot that does this, but the documentation *allows* for it.

And that's what you should be concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical point of view, you can argue that a pointer is simply the index into the memory. However, a pointer is not an int, because they can have different sizes.
A pointer is stored in the way the hardware dictates it. On some machines it can be an int, but you shouldn't rely on this.

Specifically related to programming languages, they have to take into account the object size they are pointing to, so the arithmetics is different when looking at the absolute values. In this regard it is different from a simple `int`

Answer (score 1):

There's one counter-example to consider. The early x86 processors used a segmented memory architecture, where an address was built up from *two* integers. C and C++ compilers were required to use a definition of a pointer that could accommodate these needs.

Comment: Current x86 still use segmented memory, but it not so obvious anymore because the address space is larger. the underlying architecture is still rather similar.

Comment: @Devolus, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Later_developments) that's no longer the case in 64-bit mode. And it's effectively no longer the case in 32-bit mode since the OS allocates memory as one big segment starting at zero.

Comment: That the Os allocates a single 32bit page is a convenience, and just a special setup. The architecture itself doesn't require it.

Answer (score -1):

A pointer would be a 32-bit address (on a 32-bit machine) which can indeed be cast to "int". Having said that, the math does not apply as that for integers. For instance:

```
int avar = 1;
int *aptr = *avar;
aptr++; // Will change the pointer to skip the size of the data type the pointer is pointing to
```

Comment: A pointer is not necessarily 32 bits. An `int` is not necessarily the same size as a pointer. This is all implementation-dependent.

Comment: Of course, it is not. But for a naive example, it should be good.

Answer (score -3):

Pointers variables use 4 bytes to store its address on the stack, but maintain a positionand the tracking memory on the heap, which is where the reference to which are attached, indicating that memory where reference can hacerce as large as memory space has a computer available

Comment: Which particular implementation are you refering to? There is no rule that a pointer has to be four bytes exactly.

Comment: In C/C++ each pointer variable have 4 bytes to store it address in stack.   int *ptr;  sizeof( ptr ) = 4

Comment: @jvra: No. Counter-example: on my machine, `sizeof(int*) == 8` (64 bits) and I know microprocessors where it's 2 (16 bits).