# C pointer referencing another pointer in functions

Tags: c, pointers

I discovered that if you assign a pointer address to another pointer's address in a FUNCTION it won't change the in value in the main,
however by doing the same thing in main, it will change. So what is the reason of this?

```
void func(int *a, int *b){
     b = a;
 }


int main(){
   int i= 5, k =6, *a=&i, *b=&k;
   printf("%d %d\n",*a,*b);  //output 5 6
   b = a;
   printf("%d %d\n",*a,*b);  //output 5 5

   a=&i;
   b=&k;
   func(a,b);
   printf("%d %d\n",*a,*b);  //output 5 6
   printf("%d %d\n",*a,*b);  //output 5 6
}
```

Comment: Because you passed the pointers by copy, and then changed the copies of the pointers.

Comment: BTW, you never call the function. Is that a copying error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function

```
void func(int *a, int *b){
     b = a;
 }
```

parameters a and b are local variables of the function. After exiting the function they will be destroyed. The function deals with copies of arguments. If you want that the function would change the original arguments themselves you have to pass pointers to them. For example

```
void swap(int **a, int **b){
     int *tmp = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = tmp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
void func(int *a, int *b){
     b = a;
 }
```

doesn't do anything, it just takes two values representing memory addresses as parameters and assigns one to the other without any external effect whatsoever. It just writes the value of the one to the other (probably not even that, because the compiler will likely detect this is pointless and eliminate it altogether), it doesn't do anything with the information stored at those addresses. You will need to deference the pointer to read or write to the memory address it holds the value of, but in the present form, the function will not assign the pointer to the other, but the value of `i` to `k`.

If you want a function to change a parameter outside of it, you should pass by reference, which in C is just pass by pointer, so you need to pass a pointer to the pointer, not the pointer - which will pass a copy of that pointer - the same value, while passing as pointer to pointer will pass the address of the pointer in memory, not the value it holds.

So it should be:

```
void func(int **a, int **b){
     *b = *a;
 }
```

and `func(&a,&b)` and you will reproduce what you do in `main` via `b = a`.

Comment: There's no unsigned integers here

Comment: The pointer is a memory address, the memory address is an unsigned integer. A "pointer" is just a lexical abstraction for an unsigned integer. It's not some "magic", just an unsigned integer.

Comment: if you don't accept the C standard as authoritative, then [here is some related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114343/are-pointers-stored-as-integers)

Comment: I don't care much for hypotheticals, what I care is what happens in reality. Fact is I've never had an instance of not being able to cast pointers to same width unsigned integers and back to pointers without any problem whatsoever. The C standard has a certain amount of ambiguity for the sake of compatibility with exotic platforms long extinct, but even if still there that's obsolete legacy garbage that no longer applies nowadays. Feel free to think of pointers as magic if it makes you happier, for me it is just memory addresses.

Comment: Also, that linked answer says "you are not supposed to use them as integers" but pointer arithmetic is exactly that, and pointer arithmetic is a given, not some "hit or miss" ordeal.

Comment: Why would I ever do that? For what possible purpose?

Comment: You still haven't answered what is the practical side to doing that.

Comment: Be a dear and find me implementation details where the pointer is not implemented as an integer. That would convince me.

Comment: "Pointers are implemented as integers" is a different claim to "Pointers are integers"

Comment: Mayhaps I should explain about god and the purpose of life while I am at it? Now you are just nitpicking. There is a reason I present pointers as mere numbers to the OP, because then he will be able to understand the concept better than if looking at pointers as mysterious magic, which is the N1 reason people have problems with getting pointers in the first place.

Comment: The #1 reason people have trouble with pointers is that they are told pointers are integers (and that arrays are pointers), then get confused when they don't behave like integers.  Treating pointers as things that point is much simpler.  `int *` points at an `int`. Add `1` to it, it points to the next `int`.  Add two pointers - doesn't make sense (and therefore, not possible). Subtract two pointers of type `int *` - tells you how many `int`s there were between the two. Subtract two pointers of different type - doesn't make sense; not possible. Integers don't behave like any of that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - maybe this works for you, but "things pointing to things" was never really enough for me, I had to understand the binary layout underneath. That's what I like about C and C++ - it is close to the hardware, it is not Java or whatever other language, where those things are abstracted away altogether. Anyway, I edited the question just so that you can get some sleep tonight and not torment yourself...

Comment: Removing the words "numbers representing" would be good. "memory addresses" is sufficient, it doesn't need to be limited to particular addressing schemes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - no it won't because it won't illustrate it is still an act of assigning one number to another. The context then would be "assigning one memory address to another" which ... is what exactly? That would imply there would be two cells of memory with the same address? Not confusing at all, aside from perfectly possible /s ;)

Comment: Assigning one variable to another is the same for any type of variable in C, there is no special case for pointers or structs or anything.  After the assignment, both pointer variables hold the same value.   The value of a pointer is a memory address; the value of an integer is a number. You're suggesting that beginners may be confused about the difference between a variable's address and that variable's value, which is true, but that can be dealt with by being careful about terminology (and it should have been explicitly learnt pretty early on in the learning process).

Comment: @MattMcNabb so now a number is not a value? What beginners are confused is the preposterous standard which goes about very simple concepts in ridiculously absurd ways, utterly counterproductive to understanding programming, which is understandable considering those were neither written by nor for beginners, nor even optimally well for that matter. Are you sure the name isn't McNagg? ;)

Comment: Numbers can be values, but not all values are numbers. Rigour is important in programming.