# simple c scanf is not reading and parsing my input

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have created `Date struct` to store date format as `date`, `month`, `year` which is inputed by the user as a single line string seperated by space.

I want to split the input and store it accordingly. I have used simple **`C`** `sscanf()` to split and store my input in `struct Date`. But when I try to print my data it's showing some garbage value, I don't know what is missing.

Help me to clear this issue.

My code:

```
Input: 24 Jan 1980
output: 24 ? -978635323
```

here is my C code.

```
struct Date 
{
  int date;
  char* month;
  int year;
};

int main()
{
  struct Date date[1];
  char* string;
  scanf("%s",string);
  sscanf(string,"%d %s %d",&date[0].date,date[0].month,&date[0].year);
  printf("%d %s %d",date[0].date,date[0].month,date[0].year);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to allocate memory for string. For example `char *string = malloc(MY_MAX_LEN);` Currently your code doesn't set `string` and hence it is a junk/invalid pointer and writing to it with `scanf` results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: `string` is declared to be a pointer. A pointer is a variable that is used to store the address of some memory. So you need some memory (which `malloc` for example gives) and you need to set `string` to that memory address.

Comment: What about strdup() ?

Comment: `strdup` requires an original string to copy from. You don't have an original string. You are reading something from `STDIN`.

Comment: Besides allocating memory for a string (instead of a pointer), consider using `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Comment: How can I use it in Loop. Let say I need to get Set of inputs from user and need to sort it based on date.

Comment: You can use memset to reinitialize the array when you need to reuse the memory

Comment: Suggestion: `struct Date { int date; char month[4]; int year; };` ... and `if (sscanf(string, "%d%3s%d", &date->date, date->month, &date->year) != 3) /* error */;`

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [your earlier question that was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202125/simple-c-scanf-not-reading-input)

Answer (score 1):

`char* string` is an uninitialized pointer, it cannot hold a string, you need to allocate memory, initialize it as an array of chars or point it to a variable with memory already allocated or to an existing array of chars.
Your structure member `month` suffers from the same problem.

A `-Wall` flag in your compiler should give you a warning:

> ```
> 'string is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]'
> ```

Another problem is that `%s` only gets a string, when it finds a blank space, it stops reading, so it can only read `24` in your case.

Though `"%[^\n]s"` can work, a better solution would be to use `fgets`, it's a safer function since you can limit the size of the input to the size of receiving container, unlike `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

struct Date 
{
  int date;
  char month[SIZE];
  int year;
};

int main()
{
  struct Date date[1];
  char string[SIZE];
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); 
  sscanf(string,"%d %s %d",&date[0].date, date[0].month, &date[0].year);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it works for me. You can check it.

```
struct Date
{
    int dat;
    char month[20];
    int year;
};

int main()
{
    struct Date date[1];
    char str[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
    sscanf(str,"%d %s %d",&date[0].dat,&date[0].month,&date[0].year);
    printf("%d %s %d",date[0].dat,date[0].month,date[0].year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost there, in `sscanf()`, `&date[0].month` is of type `char (*)[20]`, `%s` is of type `char*` use `date[0].month`. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/yFelJXh9uuy4GGuO

Comment: If input is only `"\n"`, then `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)` writes nothing to `str` and following `sscanf(str, ...` leads to undefined behavior.  Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

> **EXPLANATION**

In your code, you have declared two `char *` pointers `char *month` and `char *string`, and trying to store string values in them. You have to understand that these two are mere pointers. All they can store are memory addresses to `char` arrays. It is true that an array variable is interchangeable with a pointer in C. But an array declaration also involves a size attribute.

When you declare a character array as:

```
char str[10];
```

It actually reserves a block of size 10 in memory, implicitly creates `char *str`, and stores the base address of the newly created block in `str`. But when you just declare `char *str`, all it does is create a pointer. This doesn't have any associated memory block for the array.

That's why you have to declare a character array of some size before storing strings in it with `scanf()`. Or you have to dynamically allocate memory with `calloc` or `malloc` after declaring the `char *` pointer. Only then can you store a string input in it.

I have modified your code to work properly. It produces the desired output now. Hope this helps.

> **WORKING CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Date 
{
  int date;
  char month[10];
  int year;
};

int main()
{
  struct Date date[1];

  char string[20];

  scanf("%[^\n]s",string);
  sscanf(string,"%d %s %d",&date[0].date,date[0].month,&date[0].year);
  printf("%d %s %d",date[0].date,date[0].month,date[0].year);

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

<s>They themselves are integers actually (as are all pointers).</s>
As mentioned by [anastaciu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6865932/anastaciu), pointers are not equivalent to integers per se. You can follow the links given in his comments for more knowledge. I had mentioned that statement to assert the difference between pointers and array declarations.

Comment: Pointers are not just integers, it's more complicated than that, even their sizes are usually different deppending on the platform, see https://wandbox.org/permlink/BjRgO4VutCMKxzMg, you can also see [Is pointer just an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199805/is-pointer-just-an-integer) and [Are pointers stored as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114343/are-pointers-stored-as-integers).

Comment: @anastaciu I was aware of the fact. It was an oversimplification on my part to make the OP understand. I think my post touches on all of his doubts and makes an effort to clarify the same. And thank you for the posts. I learned something more today. It is easy to imagine pointers as integers. The reason I had stated that was to distinguish them from array declaration. I'll make an edit to my answer to highlight your point. It'll be nice if you can remove the downvote.

Comment: @anastaciu Thanks anyway mate. It helped me make the answer better.